# How do you display an error message on a web page when IIS ProcessRequest throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a html page with ajax that has a form that is returning a value that triggers:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client.

We have a wrapper class inserted between our ASPX C# code and the base classes that implements `ProcessRequest` (along with other calls); the primary purpose of the wrapper class being to log exceptions to our own logging mechanism.

When we get the invalid data error, we would like to display a meaningful alert but run into the `PageRequestManagerParserErrorException` which, while it tells a developer what the issue is, is useless to an end user.

Things which haven't worked:

- `Response.write` (which is documented elsewhere as the cause for the parse error)
- `RegisterStartupScript`
- `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

I saw the post about handling file uploads which are too large but it doesn't address the issue of outputing an error message to the user.

Comment: RegisterClientScriptBlock should work as long as there are no other error's for example if it raises an error during a the process of a PostBack prior to Page_Load can you show the RegisterClientScriptBlock that you are using as well as the error message that you want to raise.. I created a Method where you can pass in error message and if you need to redirect to another page etc.. let me know if you would like me to post that for you..

Comment: Do you have ValidationSummary on the page

Comment: there is an asp:validationSummary on the page and its inside the contentTemplate for the ajax update panel.

Comment: the client script block is getting accepted (its contents are a javascript block to put up an alert), but it never gets invoked.

Comment: the client script block is getting accepted (its contents are a javascript block to put up an alert), but it never gets invoked.

right now, i've updated by global.asax to handle the dangerous data exception and have it return a 500 level http status code which is intercepted by ajax and at least lets the user know there is an issue instead of having the screen appear non-responsive.